# What is "import ..." python syntax supposed to mean?

Tags: django, import

What does "import …" mean in Python?  I see it in Django files but no explanation in Python 3.8 documentation.  Not one comment about what the "..." is supposed to mean.

Comment: Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

Comment: If you mean literally `import ...` with the three dots in code, that should be a syntax error. Maybe `from ... import *` or similar? You should show where you saw it.

Comment: If that is in Django documentation, it probably means "you need to import the relevant things", and you are supposed to work out what the relevant things are from the context.

Comment: The problem is that I started using PyCharm and the behavior is in PyCharm rather than in Python or Django.  I just started using it.  I should have stuck to VSCode?  Live and learn.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay . . . the problem was that I installed PyCharm (community edition), which COLLAPSES all of the imports into one line that reads "import . . .".  If you want to see all of the imports, you have to CLICK on that line.  How silly. The "Import . . ." line is in fact an artifact of PyCharm.  I have never seen that behavior in any other IDE that I have used.  All of the others just show you EVERY LINE OF CODE.